# Поиск из localStorage

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

Здравствуйте.

При вводе сообщения в формате "#тег сообщение", сообщение сохраняется в localStorage

При вводе только одного тега, связанные с этим тегом сообщения должны динамически считаться из localStorage и вывестись на экран (без нажатия на кнопку или enter)

Не знаю как решить эту задачку, ребят. Кровно прощу помощи.

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ["ngStorage"]);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,$localStorage){

  if ($localStorage.todoList || []) {
    $scope.todoList = $localStorage.todoList || [];
    $scope.todoMassive =  $scope.todoList ;
  }


$scope.todoAdd = function() {

      var message = $('#message').val();
        var count = message.indexOf(' ');
      var hashtag = message.substring(0, count)
        if(hashtag[0] != '#') hashtag = '#' + hashtag;
         var text = message.substring(count, message.length);

    $scope.todoList.push({ 
      hashtag:hashtag ,
      todoText:text  
    });

    $scope.todoMessage = "";
    $scope.todoHashTag = "";   

    $localStorage.todoList = $scope.todoList;

  console.log($scope.todoList);

};


  $localStorage.todoList = $scope.todoList;

});
```

codepen.io/endoneslife/pen/yabwNA

Comment: код должен быть непосредственно в вопросе, ссылка может быть дополнением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы это работало, тебе достаточно добавить фильтр в строке с ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in todoList | filter: todoMessage">
```

Вот твой пример с работающим фильтром [CodePen](http://codepen.io/artemnikolaev/pen/qajdAz)

Comment: Спасибо огромное )